# One to many with RedBeanPhp ORM

Tags: php, orm, redbean

I would like to retrieve some records of a linked table :

```
table "portfolio" :
-id
-title

table "portfolio_img" :
-id
-image
-id_portfolio
```

The `{id_portfolio}` field is the foreign key of the "portfolio" table : `{id}` field.

How can I get all the `"portfolio_img"` records using an `{id_portfolio}` field (not using the classic way of `R::find()`, of course ;) ) ?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way redbean is designed, you would need to rename the field to `portfolio_id`.  Then you would be able to access all the images by calling the `portfolio` bean and the `own` attribute.

```
$portfolio=R::load('portfolio',1);
echo $portfolio->title;
foreach($portfolio->ownPortfolio_img as $img){
    echo $img->image;
}
```

Now you can add an image as well, using:

```
$image=R::dispense("portfolio_img");
$image->image="myimage.jpg";
$image->portfolio=R::load('portfolio',1);
R::store($image);
```

I do a similar thing in my scripts (one to many - Company to Contacts).

Comment: how we can do this opration from other side...means add a image to portofilo->ownImageList ?